# Why does my background color go beyond the size of node in Javafx FXML application?

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

My scene is:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 220);
```

in FXML, Grid pane is:

```
<GridPane fx:id="base"
      alignment="CENTER"
      maxHeight="200.0"
      maxWidth="300.0"
      stylesheets="@style.css"
      vgap="0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="sample.Controller">
...
```

CSS for gridpane:

```
-fx-background-color: red;
```

Even though my gridpane's max height and width are 200 and 300 respectively, the background goes beyond that covering the whole scene. I have made the background red to make it apparent.
[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRf5N.png)

Can anyone explain this, please? And what is the way of making the background limited to only gridpane instead of the whole scene?

Comment: The root node will fill the scene, irrespective of any max size settings. Try wrapping it in another pane: `Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(root), 320, 220);`

Comment: Just to get an inquiry about whether I understood, you mean I have to make a dummy root node which will just be a container for my Grid Pane?

Comment: Not really a "dummy" root node, but yes, a root node that lays out your grid pane, respecting its max size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Scene` performs no layout to speak of. The root of the `Scene` will fill the dimensions of the `Scene` regardless of any maximum (or minimum) size that has been set. So what is happening here is not that the "background color is going beyond the size of the node" so much as the node is filling the scene (and taking on a size larger than the max size you set). Basically, there is nothing that is managing the size of your `GridPane` and ensuring it doesn't grow beyond the maximum size you set for it.

To ensure your `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` are respected, you need to place the grid pane in a layout pane that will perform layout and pay attention to those properties. So you can do:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(root), 320, 220);
```

which will place the `GridPane` (`root`) in a `StackPane`. The `StackPane` manages the layout of `root` and ensures it doesn't grow beyond the maximum size you have set.

You can of course include the `StackPane` (or whatever you choose to manage the `GridPane`) in the FXML instead, if you prefer.

Perhaps off-topic, but if you are looking to have a gap between the grid pane and whatever surrounds it, you might consider doing this purely in your CSS:

```
#base {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, red ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 10 ;
    -fx-padding: 10 ;
}
```

Then you can add the grid pane directly to the scene, and (while it still fills the scene) it has a 10 pixel transparent border around the edge.

Note the CSS solution behaves differently to the first solution when you resize the window, so these are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You check in css whether you have applied the background color for grid pane or to the scene.
Or you can apply background color to gridPane through code itself as given below.
Try this..

```
gridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
```

Comment: my CSS is:
`#base {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-background-size: 100%;
}`
you can see in my fxml that fx:id is base. So, it should not be problem there.

Comment: I tried doing setStyle, too. Came with the same result.

Comment: try with prefHeight and prefWidth for gridpane